# Proving the continuity of a function in its domain

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

"Show that the following two functions are continuous in their domain.

$h(x) = xe^{\sin(x)}$

$g(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{x^2-2}$

So I know that to prove continuity I need to show that $f(a)$ is defined, the limit to a exists, and that the limit is $f(a)$. But I'm not entirely sure how I would do that in this case as the first function has a domain of all real numbers and the second one is defined everywhere except between $-3$ and $3$. So how I prove that it is continuous throughout the domain? I'm only used to proving continuity at a given point.

Any help?

Comment: "I need to show that f(a) is defined" No, you don't. By definition of "domain", $f(a)$ automatically exists for all relevant $a$. Which $a$ are relevant will, of course, require some kind of argument.

Comment: I hate these kind of questions. A function, by definition, comes with a domain. It shouldn't be up to you to find the domain. The question would make sense if it asked for the maximal domain which is a subset of the reals such that the function is well defined. Then ask to show continuity.

Comment: You simply have to prove $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$ for any $a$ in the domain.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The function $h$ is a product of two continuous function. What about the expoonential factor? This is a composition of two continuous function: an exponential one and the sine. The composition of continuous functions is continuous. Try to handle $g$ in tha similar manner.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$h(x)$ is a **composition of continuous function** thus it is continuous $\forall x\in \mathbb{R} $ the function ( it’s a theorem)

$g(x)$ also is a composition of continuous functio but not $\forall x\in \mathbb{R} $ in this case you have to find $x$ value for which the **function is defined**, that is:

$$x^2-9\geq0$$

$$x^2-2\neq0$$